# How to defend Mathematics from "ignorant" people?

Tags: reference-request, education, math-history

Some of my friends are blaming me to stop talking about and studying Math. But I love Math so much and I do Math almost everyday. The problem is that some of my friends told me "go and get a life". I am asking this question because I would like to hear from experienced  and professional people what is wrong with these points (see below) and how to justify to people (like my friends) that Math is not only virtual things.

They told me a lot of things but I remember few of them now:

- How do $\pi$ being irrational helps you in your life? When did you use this in your whole life?
- Did you ever use or see in your life a matrix?
- $A$ is singular. Great, and $\cdots$?
- Suppose you get the integral of a function $f$ and then what?
- $\cdots$.

I believe that Mathematics is used everywhere but I could not give argument to these friends. (Maybe for the integral I said that it measures an area and we use it in our life and somehow they are convinced).

Do you know a good reference that I must read so I can defend my beliefs about math? Or I have just ignore them and that's it?

Thanks.

P.S. I am doing a PhD on Theoretical Computer Science and I still do math (all kind of levels everyday). My friends are working in industry.

Comment: In such situations, talk about money.  Ask them to give you all of their money.  Hand them back a fraction of what they gave you. If they refuse, or object, then you've proved that they do like math.  Otherwise, pocket the money -- they are a hopeless case, and you are richer for it.

Comment: Wow, your friends sound like jerks. Even if mathematics had no value outside of itself, these are awfully rude things to say about someone's hobby/interest/passion. Notice that all the things they ask about maths could be equally well asked about baseball, or art, or crochet, or whatever else your friends are into.

Comment: And mathematics does have great applicability in all kinds of areas - in technology (google ...), finance, etc. Math is ubiquitous in modern life.

Comment: On the other hand, another possibility is that maybe you talk about maths so much that you're boring your friends and they're trying to get you to cut it out.

Comment: Firstly, talking about something that the other person isn't interested in it won't do you any favors. Anyway, the "but it's not useful!" one is as bizarre as it is common, I would just counter by asking them what they get out of eating chocolate. I suspect this comes from having been *forced* to learn math - you might see similar attitudes if you forced people to eat chocolate against their will.

Comment: Also, those particular examples are very poor because of how specific they are. Challenging a mathematician to defend the beauty of math through the example of determining if a matrix is singular would be like asking an painter to explain the value of art by talking about how they mix their pigments.

Comment: Why do you feel that you need to defend your beliefs? if you talk about it non stop, I am not surprised they become tired of it. If however they undermine your beliefs without provocation, this says more about them than you, surely?

Comment: PhD in computer science and don't know the significance of matricies!!

Comment: Your friends are right: stop talking mathematics with them! Friends are to have good time with them, to talk to, confess to, get/give support in rough times, etc. They don't have to suffer your infatuation with mathematics. In university you will have **other** friends with whom talk about it and anything esle related to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the same argument about their job. If they're not farmers or something, probably what they do is more useless (well, I'd rather use redundant) than math.

Their objections are particulary stupid, too. I could understand if someone said something like "Zariski's topology, what the heck" , but really? The integral? Everything that they wear/use/eat makes use of integrals.
A is singular, well? Well the thing you're building may explode, have fun.
Also they should use matrices everyday in industries; if they don't, surely what clever people make them do does.

The $\pi$ question is the only one that kinda makes sense, however since it's a fundamental constant maybe knowing it's not a root of any polynomial is kinda useful. Since that polynomial would have awesome properties.

tl;dr change friends.

Answer (score 8):

In the actual world of smartphones and computer, I think that a good example of application of maths is the Fourier transform. I always introduce it as follow. First you ask the people to try to imagine how can your TV show a picture just by plugging a cable. There is something beautifully "magic" behind this fact. This is part of the signal processing which is (or was at least) almost completely based on the Fourier transform. This shows that without maths, no screen. And without screen, no cell phones, no computers, no playstation (I'm sure you'll find something that will concern directly your friends). Last thing to note is that Fourier probably wouldn't have found his results if he didn't knew how to compute an integral, what is pi and so on...
At the end, knowing how to determine whether $A$ is singular or not is as useful as knowing how to boil water. You don't need it until you're hungry and want to cook pastas.

Comment: I please you to excuse my bad english :)...

Answer (score 5):

Watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=04WJEEb33CY) and/or just ignore that sort of people.

Use your energy for better, more pleasurable things.

Answer (score 3):

I take it your friends don't work in the kind of industry that uses math. Math and science are making themselves known behind the scenes in practically every aspect of our daily lives - what we eat, wear, drive, and *do*. It's in our electronic devices, our vehicles, our bank accounts. It's in the science-fiction-esque technology that allows us to go to the moon or map the sea's floor or see moving pictures on screens and hear things from holes in plastic devices or blow up entire cities instantaneously or map the universe through cosmic intervals of space and time - past, present, future, and lightyears of distance. Just because something seems tedious, dry, pointless, irrelevant doesn't mean it is to those who understand its significance and actively wield its power.

Savvy observers can distinguish between applied math and pure math, and ask what the latter has to say for itself. Like any hobby or passion or art or form of inquiry, it doesn't need to justify its existence with real-world use. (Personally, I've always taken to math as a form of escapism, as opposed to  something to tame life with.) But it does need to justify itself to society and government and corporations and comittees and citizens as something that requires our collective support - financially, culturally, bureaucratically. There is a spectrum or continuum of sorts between pure and applied, and everyone on this spectrum depends on their immediate neighbors for all sorts of insight, inspiration, understanding, experience and reference. Bolstering one end of the spectrum in the real world has run-off: it leaks strength into the other areas in education and hence industry.

There is also no telling when a serendipitous discovery fundamentally alters this spectrum, and turns something pure and applicationless into a staple of the modern world as we know it with global repurcussions. This has already happened for quantum mechanics with the nuclear bomb and logic with computers and number theory with crypto-security. Who knows what's next?

Answer (score 2):

Well this is a social and personal question rather than a mathematical. I suppose the first thought I have is that if they are your friends, why are they not supporting you in what you want to do ? I think they are probably not so happy in their own life, so they want you to be just like them, it helps them to justify their own decisions.
It might be helpful to cultivate some new friendships with people already turned onto math. Finally, I think trying to justify your interest in math to other  does people is a waste of time, maybe when you are with these people focus on what you have in common, avoid math, and if math comes up treat it with a little humor. Take delight in knowing "useless" things. What does it do for you life ? It gives you pleasure.